# Cannot access blockchain.info through Tor browser?

Tags: blockchain.info, bitaddress.org

I created my first wallet using bitaddress.org and put some money in it, which I am not able to spend, since this wallet doesn't have that function. 
So I decided to import this wallet to blockchain wallet. 
The problem is when i try to access blockchain wallet section through Tor it shows me a page with the following error message - Quota Exceeded (Req Count Limit).
Can someone help. Do you have any suggestions why I get this?
At this moment all my bitcoins are stuck into my bitaddress wallet and I cannot use them.

Comment: Are you accessing the clearnet or Tor page for BCI? Ie [https://blockchainbdgpzk.onion/](https://blockchainbdgpzk.onion/)

Comment: sounds dodgy to me, looks like blockchain want to execute a java script on the login page, i also have same prob and cannot login, i get similar message or an "unable to establish session" message, not good.

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue with their TOR service for over a year.  They claim that they're trying to fix the problem, but I don't believe them anymore.  They can't be this incompetent.  Their service is pretty much unusable.  If I knew of a decent alternative, I'd switch immediately and never use blockchain.info again.